# Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin' is not at first place

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems, jekyll, rvm

I have tried so many different threads but cannot fix my issue. I am trying to get Jekyll working, it was, but suddenly it is not letting me.

I get the following error when I run 'rvm -v':

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/bin' is not at first place.
     Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for 'PATH=...' entries.
     You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles'.
     To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.10'.
     To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.
```

rvm 1.29.2 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io/]

I do not know understand what it means about searching for PATH entries and how I would change them.

I have tried https://rvm.io/rvm/install and updated Ruby and removed bundler and jekyll but to no joy. When I update ruby, when I close the window, it just goes back to the older version, which is:

```
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin11.0]
```

When I try to run

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources
```

when I do

```
jekyll serve
```

now, it says

```
-bash: jekyll: command not found
```

I am on Sierra 10.12.6.

Comment: For the PATH issue, try `echo $PATH` and `which rvm` for starters.

Comment: According to the warning message you posted, rvm wants `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/bin` to be the first thing in your `PATH`. Open `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.bashrc` and look for anything that looks like `export PATH=`. (If any of these files are empty when you open them then make sure to close them without saving them.)

Comment: Hi @DavidWiniecki, I have found those 3 files and done 'which rvm' and 'echo $PATH' and get the following:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kyr4jo5pa1w0hce/Screenshot%202017-08-19%2017.58.18.png?dl=0

These are the 3 files I have edited, but the:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b0824f0mjc66u5n/Screenshot%202017-08-19%2018.03.16.png?dl=0
   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:

is always before the one I need to be first.

Comment: I don't know if this will fix the warning, but if you want to set up those files the way that rvm seems to intend, you should remove the line that includes "2.4.0" from .profile and .bashrc and remove the line that includes "source" from .bashrc. Then close all your terminal windows and open a new one. Then try `type rvm | head -n 1` and you should see `rvm is a  function`. Then `rvm list` to see if you have any rubies installed with rvm. Then use `rvm install ruby` to install a ruby if you don't have any installed with rvm.

Comment: Then use `rvm use (your rvm ruby's name) --default` to use that ruby by default when you open a new terminal window.

Comment: If you do the above then you will probably then need to `gem install jekyll` again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to tell you how to remove the warning in your question.
But the following should help you getting started with `jekyll`

irrespective of your `RUBY_VERSION`, update your `rubygems` package first:

```
$ gem update --system
```

then, first try installing `jekyll` gem without `sudo`:

```
$ gem install jekyll
```

*only retry with `sudo` if above step fails.*
Otherwise, you should be able to run `jekyll` commands now. Try checking its version:

```
$ jekyll -v
```

To best use recent versions of Jekyll, its best to have Bundler installed as well. So run `$ gem install bundler` as well.

Then proceed with creating a new Jekyll project.

Comment: Hi, when I do that and get to eh jekyll-v command, I get the following error:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bv29zql92d5eouo/Screenshot%202017-08-19%2017.55.24.png?dl=0

Comment: according to the trace, the error seems to be coming from `nokogiri` which is a dependency of the `amp-jekyll` plugin

Comment: A thing to note is, never create a Jekyll project in your `HOME` directory. Create a new directory to house Jekyll projects. Also, if the current directory is not a Jekyll Project, but has a `Gemfile` move to inside a Jekyll project directory and then run `$ bundle exec jekyll -v`